# Can I change a varchar to Date with Day name

Tags: mysql, date, varchar

Is it possible to change from a Varchar to Date format in Mysql but with a day name ie

Current Date format
Monday 16th September 2013

I actually like to have the day 'Monday' included but my issue seems to be ordering by date actually orders alphabetically so would like to convert to Date format if possible.

Thank you

Comment: [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Comment: Sorry for the message being ambiguous, STR_TO_DATE() I can get to work on 1 date, but the column contains many dates and would like to convert the whole column.  thank you for your reply.

Comment: Just replace the function's ***`str`*** argument (i.e. its first one) with your column reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like eggyal says,

```
  SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Monday 16th September 2013','%W %D %M %Y')
```

does the job for the date layout you specify.

This will also work for a column containing dates. For example, if you have these dates in a column:

```
what_day
Monday 16th September 2013
Tuesday 17th September 2013
Thursday 19th September 2013
Friday 20th September 2013
Saturday 21st September 2013
Thursday 19th September 2013
```

You can do

```
 SELECT what_day
   FROM days
  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(what_day,'%W %D %M %Y')
```

to get the days in date order. See this:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74c58/1/0

Beware, MySQL isn't checking your dates for much validity. It ignores the day of the week.  And, if you put in 31st September 2013 (not a valid date) MySQL thinks, reasonably, that you mean 1st October, 2013.

This makes it possible to do all kinds of nice date arithmetic like

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Monday 16th September 2013','%W %D %M %Y') 
       - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER
```

It also allows proper sorting.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, as my message was a little vague, is something like this suitable for a whole column of dates as I can only use this on an individual date basis.  thank you

Comment: The Date column is called Date and the Table is called TEST, so I have used the following SELECT `Date`
   FROM TEST
  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%W %D %M %Y') which returns just the dates (obviously) but not converted to the date format, they still show Monday 16th September 2013 format.  thank you again

Comment: in SQL, functions that work on constants also work on the contents of columns.  That's pretty much universal, and the whole point of having functions in SQL.

Comment: It's customary to accept the answer that helps you by clicking on the green outline check icon.

Comment: sorry, first post :-)